# Cocos run -p android, error running command, return code 1

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I was following "Building Android Games with Cocos2d-x" book page 8. And type command:

```
Cocos run -p android
```

While in the project directory. So I wait the command to finish (it was about 20 minutes), and then the process stopped after make.exe, it said wrong command. The result is here:
[image: return 1]

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are add ant root path

```
"/Users/***/Documents/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin"
```